# GUI утилита для рекурсивной перекодировки файлов

Tags: iconv, перекодировка, linux

Подскажите как рекурсивно в куче папок кучу файлов перекодировать в одну кодировку (Linux). По возможности ищу GUI решение, но не критично. Про iconv знаю. Проблема еще в том, что файлы в разных кодировках - часть в UTF8, часть в cp1251. Или это не проблема?

Comment: А зачем нужно именно GUI? Намного удобнее набросать скрипт на sh, который все сделает.

Comment: Не против и такого варианта. Не будет проблем с разными кодировками? Если я укажу iconv входную кодировку cp1251, а на самом деле будет utf8?

Comment: дык накатайте такую програмку сами. 1 вечер на логику, 1 на ГУИ.

Comment: Вот в [этом вопросе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/420667/10105) ваша проблема решена. C#/Mono на линуксе должен быть.

Answer (score 1):

Вот неплохая [ссылочка](http://ruunix.ru/134-perekodirovka-failov-v-unix.html), может поможет. Насчет GUI решения там упомянут тул kate.

Comment: kate это просто продвинутый редактор. Перекодировать в нем можно, но вручную каждый файл в отдельности.