# Перекодировать в UTF-8 с BOM

Tags: перекодировка

Есть дерево папок исходников (.cpp, .h). Большинство исходников имеют кодировку UTF-8 без BOM и возможно остались исходники в CP1251. Нужно все перевести в UTF-8 с BOM, причём сохранить структуру папок.

Пробовал UTFCast Express, но он UTF-8 без BOM распознал как ANSI. В результате перекодировал в UTF-8 второй раз, превратив исходники в кракозябры в любой кодировке.

Notepad++ распознаёт кодировку правильно, но перекодировать каждый файл по-отдельности долго.

Программа готова! Привёл её к приличному виду с GUI. [Выложена](https://devoln.github.io/projects/encoding-converter) на моём сайте. Судя по всему здесь уже было много вопросов по поводу перекодировки, и, надеюсь, моя программа поможет их решить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Давайте напишем пару вспомогательных методов (на C#):

```
Encoding strictUtf8Encoding =
    new UTF8Encoding(encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier: false, throwOnInvalidBytes: true);

Encoding strictCp1251Encoding =
    Encoding.GetEncoding(
                1251,
                new EncoderExceptionFallback(),
                new DecoderExceptionFallback());

string TryDecodeFileContent(byte[] bytes, Encoding encoding)
{
    try
    {
        var preambleBytes = encoding.GetPreamble();
        bool startWithPreamble =
                preambleBytes.Length != 0 &&
                Enumerable.SequenceEqual(preambleBytes, bytes.Take(preambleBytes.Length));
        int startByte = startWithPreamble ? preambleBytes.Length : 0;
        return encoding.GetString(bytes, startByte, bytes.Length - startByte);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }
}

string TryReadFile(string filename)
{
    var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
    return TryDecodeFileContent(bytes, strictUtf8Encoding) ??
           TryDecodeFileContent(bytes, strictCp1251Encoding);
}
```

С ними должно быть легко:

```
var text = TryReadFile(filename);
if (text == null)
    Console.WriteLine("Needs attention: " + filename);
else    
    File.WriteAllText(filename, text, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Теперь просто обойдите структуру каталогов рекурсивно.

Comment: Текст с кириллицей в кодировке Win-1251 точно не удастся прочитать как UTF-8?

Comment: У меня в эксперименте не получилось. Но гарантии дать не могу, конечно. По идее, при пакостной констелляции может (должны быть через один символы `0xD0`), но это маловероятно.

Comment: Можно добавить ещё эвристику, по идее.

Comment: А почему название TryConvertToEncoding, а не TryConvertFromEncoding? Мы ведь переводим ту кодировку, какая есть, в string, который всегда UTF-16?
 И ещё надо BOM дописать, WriteAllText ведь его сам не пишет? Кстати, у меня в папках есть ещё бинарники. По-хорошему их надо тоже детектить. Хотя в данном случае можно просто по расширению файла отбросить, так как я знаю, что там лежит. Но если уж я берусь за свою утилиту, то я делаю её не на один раз.
 Пойду искать, как рекурсивно обходить структуру каталогов.

Comment: @GLmonster `Encoding.UTF8` создаётся с `encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier=true`, бом будет записан. Если надумаете писать на шарпе, то используйте `Directory.GetFiles(".", "*.cpp", SearchOption.AllDirectories)`. :)

Comment: Отлично, а при чтении BOM если есть, будет правильно обработан?
 А как передать в Directory.GetFiles несколько разных расширений? Какой там разделитель?

Comment: @GLmonster: По идее, должен прочитать. Если не сработает, надо добавить ещё один экземпляр `utf8Encoding`. Но насколько я помню, должно читать вне зависимости от BOM.

Comment: @GLmonster: [Вот](http://stackoverflow.com/a/163220/276994). `Directory.EnumerateFiles("path", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(s => s.EndsWith(".cpp") || s.EndsWith(".h"))`.

Comment: В общем, дописал программу, всё сконвертировал, но сконвертированные исходники не компилируются. Похоже, что компилятор BOM воспринимает как идентификатор. Хотя когда я вручную конвертил через Notepad++, всё компилировалось.

Comment: Странно. А чем отличается файл, сконвертированный вручную от файла, сконвертированного кодом? Должно всё работать. Может, BOM наоборот не нужен?

Comment: Разобрался. Оказывается, те файлы, у которых был BOM после конвертации стали иметь 2 BOM'а. То есть ваш метод при чтении не убирает BOM, а при записи добавляет ещё один. Убрал лишние BOM'ы и заработало.

Comment: Хм. Это странно, по идее. Может быть, `encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier: false` неправильно? То есть тривиальная идея — проверять первые 3 байта и резать, конечно.

Comment: @GLmonster: А, понял. Я виноват: `Encoding.GetString` не убирает BOM. Сейчас исправлю.

Comment: @GLmonster: Исправил. Сейчас должно работать. Сорри!

Comment: @GLmonster: Вроде сделал ещё надёжнее. Теперь можно в production!

Answer (score 2):

Вы же программист. Напишите программу в несколько строчек, которая пройдётся по иерархии. Если у вас в коде символы win-1251, а возможных кодировок только две, то проверка кодировки простая: загрузить как UTF-8, загрузить как win-1251; одна из версий должна дать текст, в котором только символы из нужных диапазонов и никакого мусора. Переводите в нужную кодировку. И рекурсией по папкам.

Написать программу в 10 строчек быстрее, чем найти идеально подходящий инструмент.

Comment: Я как-то не был в настроении писать сам, хотел найти готовое. Но судя по всему действительно быстрее написать самому.
 Но насчёт 10 строчек сомневаюсь. Наверное строк 100 получится.

Comment: @GLmonster Если посмотреть на код Влада, то там явно не 100 строк. А дописать только перечисление файлов в директории осталось по сути — в шарпе это одна строчка кода.

Comment: Ну я же собираюсь писать по уму. А то вдруг я случайно не ту папку выберу и у меня весь диск C:\ или D:\ переконвертируется? Короче я решил написать программку с интерфейсом типа UTFcast Express и чтобы она перед конвертацией показала, какие файлы изменятся. Вот сейчас делаю. Наверное около 100 строчек уйдёт, но по-моему для такой программы это очень даже неплохо.