# Неправильное отображение шрифтов после компиляции C# в Visual Studio Community 2015

Tags: c#, кодировка, .net-4.5

Осуществил перевод плагина, написанного на C# с использованием .NET Framework 4.5. После компиляции его в Visual Studio Community 2015 шрифты отображаются неправильно (в виде кракозябров). Предыдущие переводы с использованием Visual Studio 2010 и платформы .NET Framework 4.0 проблем не вызывали. Шрифты в проекте используются только системные.

Какие-либо идеи?

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Для того, чтобы на вопрос можно было ответить, добавьте весь относящийся к проблеме код и сообщения об ошибках в сам вопрос.  Без кода невозможно угадать, где у вас ломается кодировка. Подробнее: [ask], [как создать краткий, завершенный и достоверный пример.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Идея: вы приводите минимальный воспроизводящий проблему пример, а мы думаем, в чём же может быть проблема.

Comment: Кстати, моя персональная Ванга заглянула в ваше прошлое, и видит как вы сохраняли файл не в ортодоксальной кодировке UTF-8, а в неугодном астралу CP-1251. Может быть, она права?

Comment: @Nick Volynkin исходный код здесь: http://www.boltbait.com/pdn/codelab/CodeLab26Src.zip

Comment: @VladD сохранение файла в обоих кодировках приводит к одному и тому же результату при использовании Visual Studio Community 2015. Проблема снята в результате компиляции в Visual Studio 2012 (кодировка не имела значения).

Comment: @Михаил: Вы _точно_ уверены, что сохранение файла в utf-8 не помогло? Перепроверьте. Это известный баг/фича новой версии.

Answer (score 7):

Была похожая проблема. Все ваши файлы, в которых есть текст на кирилице, вам нужно сохранить в utf-8. Это можно сделать так:

`File` → `Save as...` → `Save with encoding` (треугольник на кнопке `Save`) → Выбрать `Encoding - Unicode UTF-8` → `OK`

или

`File` → `Advanced Save Options...` → Выбрать `Encoding - Unicode UTF-8` → `OK`

Comment: ... а [вот здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/420667/10105) есть код, который позволит вам сделать это автоматически, а не вручную.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2015 некорректно компилирует кириллические строки зашитые в код ASP.NET проектов. Вынесите строки в файлы ресурсов, либо публикуйте проект через Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: компилятор тот же, генератор кода из aspx - тот же. оба вне visual studio. можете привести пример (на гитхаб?), или дать ссылку на баг на connect?

Comment: Боюсь так глубоко вопрос не изучал. Есть собственный опыт: рабочий трекер задач: BugNET с прикрученным на коленке Wiki движком. VS 2015 некорректно компилирует кириллицу зашитую в коде. Поскольку рабочего времени переносить строки в файлы ресурсов нет, то просто публикуем проект с VS 2013.

Comment: компилятор в студии действительно один и тот же - он входит в состав самого .net. попробуйте пересохранить файлы в utf-8, вдруг поможет? у задавшего вопрос, кстати, winforms, а не asp.net

Comment: я тому, что "у меня та же проблема, и я использую тот же workaround" не стоит постить как ответ. особенно если есть нормальное решение.

Comment: файлы сохранены в utf-8. Кирилица компилируется в кракозябры. Я предложил решение: перенести строки в файлы ресурсов.

Comment: сохранено в Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) и все равно кракозяблы? можете сделать минимальный пример, я запощу его на connect?